# Unit test fails to load files in Intellij using sparkSession or sparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

Reading files fails in **Intellij only**, when running unit test (does not fail with sbt command line or spark-shell, meaning the code itself is working)

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class MainAppSpec extends Specification {
    // ...

    // the line below throws error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    spark.read.format("csv").load("/home/user/my_file.csv").collect

    // the line below works
    import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}
    Paths.get("/home/user/my_file.csv")

    // ...
}
```

Version:
Spark 2.3
Intellij community 2019.3 linux

The problem is specific to Intellij, if I run in command line or using spark submit, it works. Anyone knows the reason?

Full error trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2292)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
    at com.example.MainAppSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(MainAppSpecs.scala:28)
    at org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12$$anonfun$asResult$1.apply(MatchResult.scala:344)
    at org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12$$anonfun$asResult$1.apply(MatchResult.scala:344)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:123)
    at org.specs2.execute.Result$$anon$11.asResult(Result.scala:246)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:32)
    at org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12.asResult(MatchResult.scala:344)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:32)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.AsExecution$$anon$1$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(AsExecution.scala:17)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.AsExecution$$anon$1$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(AsExecution.scala:17)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:123)
    at org.specs2.execute.Result$$anon$11.asResult(Result.scala:246)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:32)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$$anonfun$safely$1.apply(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$$anonfun$safely$1.apply(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:123)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.safely(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$result$1.apply(Execution.scala:340)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$result$1.apply(Execution.scala:340)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnvSync$1$$anonfun$apply$22$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(Execution.scala:358)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:123)
    at org.specs2.execute.Result$$anon$11.asResult(Result.scala:246)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:32)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$$anonfun$safely$1.apply(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$$anonfun$safely$1.apply(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:123)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.safely(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnvSync$1$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(Execution.scala:358)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnvSync$1$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(Execution.scala:358)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Execution.scala:142)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Execution.scala:142)
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:237)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)




java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2292)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
    at com.example.MainAppSpec$$anonfun$2.apply(MainAppSpecs.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12$$anonfun$asResult$1.apply(MatchResult.scala:344)
    at org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12$$anonfun$asResult$1.apply(MatchResult.scala:344)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:123)
    at org.specs2.execute.Result$$anon$11.asResult(Result.scala:246)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:32)
    at org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$$anon$12.asResult(MatchResult.scala:344)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:32)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.AsExecution$$anon$1$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(AsExecution.scala:17)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.AsExecution$$anon$1$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(AsExecution.scala:17)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:123)
    at org.specs2.execute.Result$$anon$11.asResult(Result.scala:246)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:32)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$$anonfun$safely$1.apply(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$$anonfun$safely$1.apply(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:123)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.safely(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$result$1.apply(Execution.scala:340)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$result$1.apply(Execution.scala:340)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnvSync$1$$anonfun$apply$22$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(Execution.scala:358)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:123)
    at org.specs2.execute.Result$$anon$11.asResult(Result.scala:246)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.apply(AsResult.scala:32)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$$anonfun$safely$1.apply(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$$anonfun$safely$1.apply(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$class.execute(ResultExecution.scala:22)
    at org.specs2.execute.ResultExecution$.execute(ResultExecution.scala:123)
    at org.specs2.execute.AsResult$.safely(AsResult.scala:40)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnvSync$1$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(Execution.scala:358)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$withEnvSync$1$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(Execution.scala:358)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Execution.scala:142)
    at org.specs2.specification.core.Execution$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Execution.scala:142)
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:237)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)



Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Would posting error details / stacktrace be a probelm?

Comment: Does the issue occur in the current release? Is it possible to share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @mazaneicha I'm updating the full trace in answer

Comment: @CrazyCoder It occurs in the latest release too.